# Getting Undefined Value Instead of String Returned?

Tags: javascript

This is test code. I'm not sure why I'm not getting the string returned on line **console.log("hasToken : " + hasToken);**? I should get it returned after 3 failed attempts. The string without the tokens (var XX) works fine but the string with the token (var X) never returns the string properly. If I step through the code I see the string being passed back but something else happens and I don't know why?  The console.log shows undefined for the hasToken value? I see where the string is suppossed to be returned.[Test Code Here](https://playcode.io/458430)

```js
var x = "//tokene.secure.adnxs.com/px?randomnumber=[timeSTAMP]&url=[URl]&newvsreturning=[NEWvsRETURNING]";
var xx = '//xwww.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/822232847/?label=_7yrCLe91H4Qj46JiAM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0';

var regex = new RegExp("/\\[URL\\]|\\[NEWVSRETURNING\\]|\\[RANDOMNUMBER\\]|\\[TIMESTAMP\\]|\\[CACHEBUSTER\\]/", "i");


function validateTokenRemoval(str) {
cnt = 0;
    function testTokenRemoved(str) {
        if ((regex.test(str))&&(cnt < 2)) {
            //if in here it still has tokens
   cnt++;
            //str = detokenizeTags(imgSrc);
   console.log(cnt + " failed : " + str);
            testTokenRemoved(str);
            
        } else {
            console.log(cnt + " passed : " + str);
            return str;
        }
    };
 
 return testTokenRemoved(str);
};

var hasToken = validateTokenRemoval(x);
var noToken = validateTokenRemoval(xx);
console.log("hasToken : " + hasToken);
console.log("noToken : " + noToken);
```

You can see my last step in the debug process [image: Return Debug image]

Comment: You don't return anything in the true-case.

Comment: `return testTokenRemoved(....)`

Comment: That is by design. It only gets returned if it fails 3 times or passes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put a `return` statement before the `testTokenRemoved(str)` in your if block, to return the return value of the recursive call:

```js
var x = "//tokene.secure.adnxs.com/px?randomnumber=[timeSTAMP]&url=[URl]&newvsreturning=[NEWvsRETURNING]";
var xx = '//xwww.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/822232847/?label=_7yrCLe91H4Qj46JiAM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0';

var regex = new RegExp("/\\[URL\\]|\\[NEWVSRETURNING\\]|\\[RANDOMNUMBER\\]|\\[TIMESTAMP\\]|\\[CACHEBUSTER\\]/", "i");


function validateTokenRemoval(str) {
cnt = 0;
    function testTokenRemoved(str) {
        if ((regex.test(str))&&(cnt < 2)) {
            //if in here it still has tokens
   cnt++;
            //str = detokenizeTags(imgSrc);
   console.log(cnt + " failed : " + str);
            return testTokenRemoved(str);
            
        } else {
            console.log(cnt + " passed : " + str);
            return str;
        }
    };
 
 return testTokenRemoved(str);
};

var hasToken = validateTokenRemoval(x);
var noToken = validateTokenRemoval(xx);
console.log("hasToken : " + hasToken);
console.log("noToken : " + noToken);
```

Ok, but why did the inspector misinformed you? Let's look inside:

- On the screenshot, the inspector isn't paused at the statement, what you try to get the value of. You may think, that isn't an issue, and it isn't, **until they are in the same scope.**
- Because the inspector paused **outside** the function you want to inspect, the `str` value of that isn't in-scope anymore.
- Finally, because you have a **different variable** named `str` **in the outer scope**, the inspector will show its value to you, while the value you want to inspect is **already `undefined`**.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm still confused. The string with no token (var xx) that  passes the first time is returned as expected. How come the string with the tokens which runs through the check in the testTokenRemoved function doesn't work once it reaches the final attempt and is returned?

Comment: I change the name of the sub-routine argument for clarity. I retested and still see the string being passed back but for some reason, the function is not returning the value to the variable  image is here ==> https://imgur.com/MVQy4CW

Comment: @MichaelJohns Sure, because you inspect the `str` variable, not `testTokenRemoved`'s return value. Select the full `testTokenRemoved(str)` expression with mouse and hover over it. You'll see that the value is returned exactly as it is logged later.

Comment: So the issue was the way I was doing my recursion but I don't understand why I saw the value being returned from the function?

Comment: @MichaelJohns Exactly.